# Illegal Character. At line '4' position '6' JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to minify one of my script and all the minify tools that I've tried gave me this error.

Error I get on Minify Tools: `Illegal Character. At line '4' position '6'`

This is the code part:

```
$('.countrycode').each(function(){
    var tagValue = $(this).attr("data-continent");
    var lttrs = tagValue == "na" || tagValue == "sa" ? "us" : tagValue;
   $(`.select-${lttrs}`).attr("disabled",false);
});
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That would be the tickmark `\`` -- is it possible your minifier isn't expecting es6+?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're likely using tools that don't support ES2015 and thus don't understand template literals. You can either fix the problem by upgrading your tools, or work around it by getting rid of the template literals (e.g., changing `` `.select-${lttrs}` `` to `'.select-' + lttrs`).

Comment: Thank you. You were right. I just replaced it as you said and it worked.